# Search Field Displaying Random Characters

Tags: search

I am having an issue with displaying the Simple Form Search field. I am getting a random string of characters. No form field appears too. Here's an example:

[image]

Any thoughts or ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I think this is an EE cache placeholder. Can you show us a little more of your code? What version of EE are you on?

Comment: I am using 2.9.2 and the example code for the form:

Comment: It's almost certainly a parse order problem with EE's built-in "magic marker". Try to make a minimal template with only a handful of EE tags, and build from there. Consider experimenting with parse=inward, if possible.

Also take a look here: http://blog.ericlamb.net/2011/05/expressionengine-and-the-mystery-of-m00o93h7pq09l8x1t49chy01z5j4tt91fgfr/ and be sure to check out the comments there as well.

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks! I have tried it on a blank template with just the Search Form code and it's still the same. This goes the same when I placed `parse="inward"`.

Comment: @Ingmar It looks like the module was uninstalled. :o

Comment: Ha! That would make sense. No worries, a lot of us have been there ...